# Angularjs select ng-change is not triggered when ng-model is initialized in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have my select like so

```
<select ng-model="id_select" ng-options="fide.id as fide.name for fide in fides" ng-change="loadInfo()">
   <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccionar</option>
</select>
```

And in my controller I have this

```
RestService.getFides().then(function(fides){

   $scope.id_select = fides;
   if(typeof $rootScope.selected_id !== 'undefined')
   {
      $scope.id_select = $rootScope.selected_id
   }
});

$scope.loadInfo = function() {
  alert("triggered!!");
}
```

My select is loading as expected with fides but when I try to set my select value with $rootScope's value ng-change function loadInfo() is not triggered but when I select in my view it works fine.

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation for `ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> Evaluate the given expression **when the user changes the input**. The expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key). **The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model**.

You need to call your event handler manually if you are changing the model programatically:

```
if (typeof $rootScope.selected_id !== 'undefined') {
  $scope.id_select = $rootScope.selected_id;
  $scope.loadInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely miss that part of the documentation.