# Why this ng-change does not fire

Tags: angularjs

I added a dropdown and hooked up the selectChange() method to the basic ng-change demo commonly found on the AngularJS site.  The problem is when the dropdown is changed the selectChange() does not fire.  Can anyone tell me why?  [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uDBOTz7ZwpClfMxnCRsR?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="changeExample">
    <script>
    angular.module('changeExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.change = function() {
          $scope.counter++;
        };

        $scope.selectChange = function(){
          alert('foo');
          $scope.counter++;
        };

      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" id="ng-change-example2" />
    <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />

    <tt>debug = {{confirmed}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>

    <select id='drpCars' ng-change="selectChange()">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="CarValue"><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try like this `<select id='drpCars' ng-model= "value" ng-change="selectChange(value)">` and `$scope.selectChange = function(value){`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs select ng-change is not triggered when ng-model is initialized in controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579186/angularjs-select-ng-change-is-not-triggered-when-ng-model-is-initialized-in-cont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this modified code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngChange-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="changeExample">
    <script>
    angular.module('changeExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.change = function() {
          $scope.counter++;
        };

        $scope.selectChange = function(value){
          alert(value);
          $scope.counter++;
        };

      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" id="ng-change-example2" />
    <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />

    <tt>debug = {{confirmed}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>

    <select id='drpCars' ng-model = "value" ng-change="selectChange(value)">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="CarValue"><br>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: so adding ng-model = "value" is all it took? Wow.    I am totally confused on what  'value' is and where it is in the model.

Comment: @ChiliYago, maybe you should take a look at my answer, which was before this one !

Comment: You have to create the function inside $scope! Like he shows:

 $scope.selectChange

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the `ng-model` attribute for `ng-change` to trigger

---

From the docs

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: anything you place inside ng-model is bound to and accessible in the scope. so ng-model="foo" can be accessed by $scope.foo in your controller